# regarding MPI communication split

Tags: mpi

I was just trying to use mpi_comm_split in my project. But I found something very strange.
Here is some sample code:

```
MPI_Comm topology ;
MPI_Init( &argc,&argv ) ;
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size ) ;
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank ) ;
if ( rank == 0 )
{
    cout << "check this:\t" << rrank << endl ;
}
MPI_Comm_split( MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank > 0, rank , &topology) ;
MPI_Comm_rank( topology, &rrank) ;
MPI_Comm_size ( topology, &ssize) ;
if ( rank == 0 )
{
    cout << "check this:\t" << rrank << endl ;
}
```

The output seems to be very strange:

```
check this: 180260968
check this: 0
```

What I don't understand is that the master (in default communication) is not in the new communication (topology). Then how come I am getting two different values for `rrank` ?
Hope it's clear what I am trying to ask. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The integer value `180260968` looks like an uninitialised variable.  It's the value of `rrank`.  Perhaps the previous call to `MPI_Comm_rank` should pass `&rrank` rather than `&rank`.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for the answer. I know that the value is uninitialized value. The problem persists even when I initialize with some value like "rrank = 1000" . The answer would be 1000, 0 . All I am trying to do is that my project conststs of two works ( one is bigger and other is smaller). So I am trying to assign one process to smaller task and remaing processes to bigger task. So,I am trying to generate new communication with differt ids (rranks) apart from default one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed by High Performance Mark, the value of `rrank` before calling `MPI_Comm_split()` is meaningless, since it is not initialized. Hence the output of this program is not strange : before calling `MPI_Comm_split()`, `rrank` can take any value and after, it is the rank of the process in the new communicator `topology`

In fact, the code you provided seems to perform exactly what you are expecting.
Here is a test code : compile by `mpiCC main.cpp -o main` and run by `mpirun -np 4 main`

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    int rank,rrank,size,ssize;
    char message[1000];

    MPI_Comm topology ;
    MPI_Init( &argc,&argv ) ;
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size ) ;
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank ) ;

    //splitting : creating two new communicators, one with rank=0, second with rank>0
    MPI_Comm_split( MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank > 0, rank , &topology) ;

    //getting rank of current process in new communicator topology
    MPI_Comm_rank( topology, &rrank) ;
    MPI_Comm_size ( topology, &ssize) ;

    sprintf(message,"after, splited rrank : %d global rank %d\n",rrank,rank);
    cout << message; 

    if(rank==0){
        //small task on process rank=0
        cout<<"rank 0, doing nothing, not expecting any message\n";
    }else{

        int b=rrank*rrank+42;
        //MPI_Bcast() over processes concerned by the big task, using communicator topology
        MPI_Bcast( &b, 1, MPI_INT, 0,topology);

        sprintf(message,"after bcast, on rank %d having %d\n",rank,b);
        cout << message; 
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

The output is

```
after, splited rrank : 0 global rank 0
after, splited rrank : 0 global rank 1
after, splited rrank : 1 global rank 2
after, splited rrank : 2 global rank 3
```

There are two new communicators named `topology`. One with only the process `rank=0` (which is his own master) and another one with processes `rank=1,2,3`. In this new communicator, `rank=1` has a `rrank=0`, `rank=2` has `rrank=1` and `rank=3` has `rrank=2`

The processes are divised in two groups, a small one (rank=0) and a big one (rank>0), ready to perform your tasks. Just use the communicator `topology` and new ranks `rrank` to perform these tasks. Something like :

```
if(rank>0){
     ...<big task here, using topology and rrank>...
}else{
     ...<small task here, on rank=0>...
}
```

The code is completed by an example of `MPI_Bcast()` over the processes concerned by the big task. rank=0 being excluded from this communicator.

Comment: Hi Francis, Thanks for your elaborated answer. I used finally your last idea to seperate tasks. I also noticed something strange. When I broadcast from master of a new communicator, the master from old communicator is also receiving. Isn't it strange ?

Comment: Hi Francis, and also the "rrank" of rank=0 shouldn't be some strange value ? as it not part of new communicator.

Comment: `MPI_Comm_split()` creates two communicators, both named `topology` : the process `rank=0` is part of a communicator named `topology`. If you broadcast `MPI_Bcast()` from `rank=1` usng `rrank=0` and `MPI_Comm==topology`, the process `rank=0` should not receive anything...I am going to edit the answer, to give an example.